# Shopify get all collections with specific template

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to create a Brands page in shopify. For that I have a custom page template `page.brands` and a custom template `collection.brands`.

Now I need to loop trough all collections and find only the ones using my custom template.

```
{% for collection in collections %}

  {{ template }} // template here returns 'page.brands' not 'collection.brands'

{% endfor %}
```

Found some solution to search by name but if I will add more collections I also have to add names to array.

Any help with that or there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in [shopify documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/collection)

```
{% for collection in collections %}
        
  {% if collection.template_suffix == "brands" %}
        
        {{ collection.title }} 
        
  {% endif %}
        
{% endfor %}
```